# Add react component in single spa microfrond end root-config

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

How can I add a react and add a component in the **root-app** ( Ex link : [Link](https://github.com/nemrosim/single-spa-examples/tree/master/root-app))?
I have tried to import the react and react-dom and add the component but it's not working and the app gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

u should add import map for react and react-dom like this

```
 "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js",
    "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
```